# How do I configure emacs to quit without confirmation?

Tags: emacs

How can I configure emacs on OS X so that it just quits without popping up a dialogue asking if I want to save files?

Please note that I'm not interested in rebinding C-x C-c or something - my desired behavior is that when I try to restart the system, emacs doesn't prevent shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

See the Emacs manual, node [Exiting](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Exiting.html). There you'll see this:

> If the value of the variable `confirm-kill-emacs` is non-`nil`, `C-x C-c` assumes that its value is a predicate function, and calls that
>   function.  If the result of the function call is non-`nil`, the session
>   is killed, otherwise Emacs continues to run.  One convenient function to
>   use as the value of `confirm-kill-emacs` is the function `yes-or-no-p`.
>   The default value of `confirm-kill-emacs` is `nil`.
>
> To kill Emacs without being prompted about saving, type `M-x
>   kill-emacs`.

And you can bind `kill-emacs` to any key (including to `C-x C-c`).